# upload images to laravel server from react native

Tags: laravel, react-native, fetch, react-native-image-picker

How should I upload my pictures to laravel server using fetch method in react native?
I am using `react-native-image-picker` in my react native project and follow that package `https://aboutreact.com/example-of-image-picker-in-react-native/`
and my response is like that

```
base64 ->  undefined
 LOG  uri ->  file:///data/user/0/proj_name/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_e100eb14-7efc-4aee-aea9-dc9d05a61b51.jpg
 LOG  width ->  300
 LOG  height ->  400
 LOG  fileSize ->  13813
 LOG  type ->  image/jpeg
 LOG  fileName ->  rn_image_picker_lib_temp_e100eb14-7efc-4aee-aea9-dc9d05a61b51.jpg
```

How I should upload that picture to my laravel back end with fetch method

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code in the backend, if your image form field name is "image" and you have a folder named "images" in storage. Your jpeg image will be saved in this directory.

```php
    $imageData = $request->image;  // Your base64 encoded
    $fileName = str_random(10) . '.jpg';

    $imageData = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $imageData);
    $imageData = str_replace(' ', '+', $imageData);

    \File::put(storage_path(). '/images/' . $fileName, base64_decode($imageData));
```

Answer (score -1):

There is the One better way Convert the file in ***FormData*** format.
you already getting the  uri, type, and fileName, so Just store in an Object Like given below. you can hardcore that Image Name as well.

```
image: {
     name: IMage Name,
     type: ImageType,
     uri: imagePath
},
```

Before sending to the Database through API's Just Create The FormData like this and Append that Image object into it and send that formdata to server.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('profile_pic', state.image);
```

Now you can send This formData to the Backend.

Comment: I imagine they're going to need more information on how to accomplish this. Can you provide more detailed instructions or, ideally, sample code for how to accomplish this? Take a look at [@Arash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68565981/3025856) as a good example of how to answer questions.

Comment: yes sure. as already he is getting the uri, type, and fileName, just he need to store these 3 things in the separate variables like and object

image: {
       name:ImageName,
        type: imageType,
         uri: imageURI
 }
 and create the FormData Variable

const formData = new FormData();

 and append that image Object in formData

formData.append('API Parameter Name', state.image);

Comment: @JeremyCaney I hope the concept is clear Now!